# Dataframe - How to keep limited number of rows and remove the rest

Tags: python, dataframe

There is a Dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'color', 'type'])
```

And the table is like this:

```
+-----+-----+-------+------+
|     | id  | color | type |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 0   | 1   | 23    | 1    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 1   | 1   | 5     | 1    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 2   | 1   | 92    | 1    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 3   | 1   | 44    | 3    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 4   | 1   | 7     | 3    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 5   | 1   | 32    | 4    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 6   | 2   | 544   | 1    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 7   | 2   | 36    | 1    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 8   | 2   | 87    | 2    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 9   | 2   | 43    | 3    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 10  | 2   | 51    | 1    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 11  | 2   | 36    | 4    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| ... | ... | ...   | ...  |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
```

I would like to keep only limited number of duplicated row in "type" column for each "id":
The limitation of duplicate value is more than 2 in this example.
The id = 1 has two rows of type 1. So the next row id = 1 and type = 1 is removed.

```
+-----+-----+-------+------+
|     | id  | color | type |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 0   | 1   | 23    | *1*    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 1   | 1   | 5     | *1*    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 2   | 1   | 92    | **1**    |  This row should be removed
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 3   | 1   | 44    | 3    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 4   | 1   | 7     | 3    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 5   | 1   | 32    | 4    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 6   | 2   | 544   | *1*    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 7   | 2   | 36    | *1*    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 8   | 2   | 87    | 2    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 9   | 2   | 43    | 3    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 10  | 2   | 51    | **1**    | This row should be removed
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 11  | 2   | 36    | 4    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| ... | ... | ...   | ...  |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
```

So the below is the final rows in the dataframe:

```
+-----+-----+-------+------+
|     | id  | color | type |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 0   | 1   | 23    | 1    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 1   | 1   | 5     | 1    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 3   | 1   | 44    | 3    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 4   | 1   | 7     | 3    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 5   | 1   | 32    | 4    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 6   | 2   | 544   | 1    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 7   | 2   | 36    | 1    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 8   | 2   | 87    | 2    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 9   | 2   | 43    | 3    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| 11  | 2   | 36    | 4    |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
| ... | ... | ...   | ...  |
+-----+-----+-------+------+
```

The below code does not work well:

```
df2 = df[(~df['type'].count>2) & df.loc[~df['id'].isin(df['id'])]]
```

What is the way to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: do a cumcount on groupby and delete any value greater than 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can do it with the sample data provided.

```
import pandas as pd
c=['id','color','type']
d=[[1,23,1], [1,5,1], [1,92,1],
   [1,44,3], [1,7,3], [1,32,4],
   [2,544,1], [2,36,1], [2,87,2],
   [2,43,3], [2,51,1], [2,36,4]]
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)
df['temp'] = df.groupby(['id', 'type']).cumcount()
df = df[df['temp'] < 2]
df.drop('temp',axis=1,inplace=True)
print (df)
```

or you can do all this in one line:

```
df = df[df.groupby(['id', 'type']).cumcount() < 2]
```

Original dataframe:

```
    id  color  type
0    1     23     1
1    1      5     1
2    1     92     1
3    1     44     3
4    1      7     3
5    1     32     4
6    2    544     1
7    2     36     1
8    2     87     2
9    2     43     3
10   2     51     1
11   2     36     4
```

Modified dataframe:

```
    id  color  type
0    1     23     1
1    1      5     1
3    1     44     3
4    1      7     3
5    1     32     4
6    2    544     1
7    2     36     1
8    2     87     2
9    2     43     3
11   2     36     4
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you. This is the best solution.